# Change parent variable using Angular and UI-Router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have the state `brand`. On the template of this state, I have some breadcrumbs. When I go to the *nested state* `brand.collections` for example, I need to update the breadcrumbs in the `brand` state.

How can I accomplish this?

```
.state('brand', {
    url: '/brands/:brandId/:brandName',
    templateUrl: 'js/modules/brands/partials/brand.html',
    controller: 'BrandController',
})

.state('brand.home', {
    url: '/home',
    templateUrl: 'js/modules/brands/partials/brand.home.html',
    controller: 'BrandController'
})

.state('brand.collections', {
    url: '/collections',
    template: 'Some collections',
    controller: 'CollectionsController'
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

inside CollectionsController

```
$scope.$emit('changeParentVar',<newVal>);
```

inside BrandController

```
$scope.$on('changeParentVar',function(event,newVal){
event.stopPropagation();
variable = newVal;
});
```

Reference http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$rootScope.Scope#methods_$on